# C# HtmlAgilityPack : Error looping throough nodes

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm looping through some `<li>` tags and within this tag there is an `<a>`  tag of `class="track-visit-website"`:

```
<li><a class="track-visit-website" href="abc1">Anchor1</a></li>
```

I want to grab the href of `<a>` tags. But in some `<li>` there is no `<a>` tags so my code is throwing error.

My Code is :

```
List<string> Website = new List<string>();
HtmlDocument hoteleWebsiteDoc = new HtmlDocument();
hoteleWebsiteDoc.LoadHtml(hotels.InnerHtml);

var hotelWebsite = from lnks in hoteleWebsiteDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                    where lnks.Name == "a" && lnks.Attributes.Contains("class") &&
                      lnks.Attributes["class"] != null &&
                      lnks.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("track-visit-website") &&
                      lnks.InnerText.Trim().Length > 0
                    select new
                    {
                     Url = lnks.Attributes["href"].Value,
                    };

foreach (var website in hotelWebsite)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(website.Url) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(website.Url))
        Website.Add(website.Url.Trim());
    else
        Website.Add(" ");
}
```

What should I do ? I thought of checking first whether the  tag exists or not and then execute the code. But how can i check whether the  tag exists or not? Or is there some other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var items = hoteleWebsiteDoc
           .DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li/a[@class='track-visit-website']");

if(items!=null)
{
    var links = items.Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
}
```

Comment: @L.B Your solution return NullReferenceException in the case where the href attribute doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

This solution take into account the possible case in which the `a` tag not contains the `href` attribute, for example :

```
<li>
   <a class='track-visit-website' href='abc1'>Anchor1</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a class='track-visit-website'>Anchor 2</a>
</li> 
<li> 
</li>
```

---

```
var hoteleWebsiteDoc = (from element in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
                        where element.ParentNode.Name.Equals("li") && 
                        element.Attributes.Contains("class") &&
                        element.Attributes.Contains("href") &&
                        element.Attributes["class"].Value.Equals("track-visit-website")
                        select new
                                 {
                                   URL = element.Attributes["href"].Value
                                 }).ToList();

foreach (var obj in hrefsList)
{
   Console.WriteLine(obj.URL);
}
```

Or if you want to keep the other solution instead you can change your code for this to check if contains the `href` attribute :

```
if (items != null)
{
   var links = items.Where(a => a.Attributes.Contains("href")).Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
}
```